# Creating a Table of Contents in HTML using Js, jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tableofcontents

I want to create an TOC in html using JS and Jquery. My HTML headings will look like this:

```
<section id="id1">
....
<section class="sidebar">
....
</section>
<section id="id2">
...
<section id="id3">
```

Now I want to create toc only for the sections without any class value and it may have nested inside another one.

Comment: what do you mean TOC?

Comment: i think Table Of Contents?

Comment: Table Of Contents. Common abbreviation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TOC

Comment: You question isn't really a question. It only says that you want to create something without even any indication whether you have started or not. So the only reply I can give is "Go ahead, good luck. Let us know when you're done."

Answer (score 0):

With the lack of information I can try to understand what you want todo.

Check out this snippet:

```
$(function(){
    var toc = $('section.sidebar');
    var ul = $('<ul />');
    toc.append(ul);
    $('section[id]]').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        var item = $('<li><a href="#'+$this.attr('id')+'">'+this.attr('id')+'</a></li>');
        ul.append(item);
    });
});
```